# I want to remove symbols from a string in dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to remove all symbols except for characters (Japanese hiragana, kanji, and Roman alphabet ) that unmatch this regex.

```
var reg = RegExp(
                r'([\u3040-\u309F]|\u3000|[\u30A1-\u30FC]|[\u4E00-\u9FFF]|[a-zA-Z]|[々〇〻])');
```

I don't know what to put in this "?".

```
text=text.replaceAll(?,"");
```

```
a="「私は、アメリカに行きました。」、'I went to the United States.'"

b="私はアメリカに行きましたI went to the United States"
```

I want to make a into b.

Comment: Do you need to keep digits?

Comment: Yes. I need to keep digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```dart
String a = "「私は、アメリカに行きました。」、'I went to the United States.'";
a = a.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\s]+', unicode: true), '') );
```

Also, if you just want to remove any punctuation or math symbols, you can use

```dart
.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\p{P}\p{S}]+', unicode: true), '')
```

Output:

```
私はアメリカに行きましたI went to the United States
```

The `[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\s]+` regex matches one or more chars other than letters (`\p{L}`), diacritics (`\p{M}`), digits (`\p{N}`) and whitespace chars (`\s`).

The `[\p{P}\p{S}]+` regex matches one or more punctuation proper (`\p{P}`)  or match symbol (`\p{S}`) chars.

The `unicode: true` enables the Unicode property class support in the regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can need to specify the Pattern (RegEx) you want to apply on your replaceAll method.

```dart
// Creating the regEx/Pattern
var reg = RegExp(r'([\u3040-\u309F]|\u3000|[\u30A1-\u30FC]|[\u4E00-\u9FFF]|[a-zA-Z]|[々〇〻])');

// Applying it to your text.
text=text.replaceAll(reg,"");
```

You can learn more about it here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html